# Connection profile for peer in separate organization and separate physical machine

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am setting up a composer network with 2 separate peers in separate machines. When I try to ping the network using the identity I issued for the second peer I get an error saying the identity must be activated. I see under '`composer identity list`' that there is an identity issued and bound,

> composer identity list -c alice-org1@bl-security-network ✔ List all
>   identities in the business network
>   -   $class:      org.hyperledger.composer.system.Identity   identityId: 
>   5254561bf2038c3f2764785ec6407d5c108b6cb59f9e4df071dd37b83748abe8
>   name:        admin   issuer:
>   ac3dbcbe135ba48b29f97665bb103f8260c38d3872473e584314392797c595f3
>   certificate:
>       """
>         -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
>         MIICATCCAaigAwIBAgIUCMlRQ75ytdGtgVj/O5F6pXgqv9kwCgYIKoZIzj0EAwIw
>         czELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxEzARBgNVBAgTCkNhbGlmb3JuaWExFjAUBgNVBAcTDVNh
>         biBGcmFuY2lzY28xGTAXBgNVBAoTEG9yZzEuZXhhbXBsZS5jb20xHDAaBgNVBAMT
>         E2NhLm9yZzEuZXhhbXBsZS5jb20wHhcNMTgwNTE2MDgxNjAwWhcNMTkwNTE2MDgy
>         MTAwWjAhMQ8wDQYDVQQLEwZjbGllbnQxDjAMBgNVBAMTBWFkbWluMFkwEwYHKoZI
>         zj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAEGcw0GV/K/L5VCmJLS/ngZsR2vq7xrKVhPt5AeoVX
>         Lgjv0aO6IxxTiialnWOdEIpFAlogu1BNSHoGFn8SDryJzaNsMGowDgYDVR0PAQH/
>         BAQDAgeAMAwGA1UdEwEB/wQCMAAwHQYDVR0OBBYEFDt6FVgrod+MFmOf8tdyw6dH
>         a0HKMCsGA1UdIwQkMCKAIFoSZq5xVRFtKJ6+doWFMgMxQsitU4s7BZ4ST0dpkFLt
>         MAoGCCqGSM49BAMCA0cAMEQCIC9XpIvaw+hnYLTHHYoUjTjrWiRQMD6991EPYZ/6
>         v4x1AiAKVVD5T7WXvrm05N4ThdpUS1BeBSCor4Wgm0fQC8ekeg==
>         -----END CERTIFICATE-----
>
> ```
> """   state:       ACTIVATED   participant: resource:org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin#alice-org1
> ```
>
> -   $class:      org.hyperledger.composer.system.Identity   identityId: 
>   6fdff74bf0ada91fb4a095114d8fa2a4547faabf7b2e9580b5d8a1ebb800d13f
>   name:        admin   issuer:
>   07290d7a00cf1fca27f0c98491478ecc0c65ced2caedfa6e0c000f80caaf50e4
>   certificate:
>       """
>         -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
>         MIICAjCCAaigAwIBAgIUNnm7Rls6K5Ay0trODVa8CXQxtyIwCgYIKoZIzj0EAwIw
>         czELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxEzARBgNVBAgTCkNhbGlmb3JuaWExFjAUBgNVBAcTDVNh
>         biBGcmFuY2lzY28xGTAXBgNVBAoTEG9yZzIuZXhhbXBsZS5jb20xHDAaBgNVBAMT
>         E2NhLm9yZzIuZXhhbXBsZS5jb20wHhcNMTgwNTE2MDgxNjAwWhcNMTkwNTE2MDgy
>         MTAwWjAhMQ8wDQYDVQQLEwZjbGllbnQxDjAMBgNVBAMTBWFkbWluMFkwEwYHKoZI
>         zj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAE1y8zJ+6ZjO5VV6/oG+qCQzGyII62AujhNkyDapp2
>         TlylMtlDX6VODtLmiXNjdlPi63NKUGYkKqoCAJh3efX866NsMGowDgYDVR0PAQH/
>         BAQDAgeAMAwGA1UdEwEB/wQCMAAwHQYDVR0OBBYEFMDKuUnac7KX/b7qSZ1x9tbD
>         0EC+MCsGA1UdIwQkMCKAIESSjMUlSEPHYNOLB9sm9pQsNYZzaqm8kY0Qwg47EzSI
>         MAoGCCqGSM49BAMCA0gAMEUCIQCbAYneZofBVmQJHdcyJl0GDTS3FhZ1Zw7+TO/I
>         NnF2IAIgMBO2zKPCg7ygkIPPrPLVnuJN1f9LmEZQmkXV1xaiqao=
>         -----END CERTIFICATE-----
>
> ```
> """   state:       BOUND   participant: resource:org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin#bob-org2
> ```
>
> Command succeeded

but it is not activated. I believe my problem may be in the connection profile for the second peer.

Below is the connection profile I wrote. I use the IP address of the other machine (20.20.20.23) for **docker services** that are running on it and '**localhost**' for services running on this peer. Is the below connection profile correct for this setup?

> ```
>  {
> "name": "my-net",
> "x-type": "hlfv1",
> "version": "1.0.0",
> "client": {
>     "organization": "Org2",
>     "connection": {
>         "timeout": {
>             "peer": {
>                 "endorser": "200",
>                 "eventHub": "200",
>                 "eventReg": "200"
>             },
>             "orderer": "300"
>         }
>     }
> },
> "channels": {
>     "mychannel": {
>         "orderers": [
>             "orderer.example.com"
>         ],
>         "peers": {
>             "peer0.org1.example.com": {
>                 "endorsingPeer": true,
>                 "chaincodeQuery": true,
>                 "eventSource": true
>             },
>             "peer0.org2.example.com": {
>                 "endorsingPeer": true,
>                 "chaincodeQuery": true,
>                 "eventSource": true
>             }
>
>         }
>     }
> },
> "organizations": {
>     "Org1": {
>         "mspid": "Org1MSP",
>         "peers": [
>             "peer0.org1.example.com"
>         ],
>         "certificateAuthorities": [
>             "ca.org1.example.com"
>         ]
>     },
>     "Org2": {
>         "mspid": "Org2MSP",
>         "peers": [
>             "peer0.org2.example.com"
>         ],
>         "certificateAuthorities": [
>             "ca.org2.example.com"
>         ]
>     }
> },
> "orderers": {
>     "orderer.example.com": {
>         "url": "grpcs://20.20.20.23:7050",
>         "grpcOptions": {
>             "ssl-target-name-override": "orderer.example.com"
>         },
>         "tlsCACerts": {
>             "pem": "INSERT_ORDERER_CA_CERT"
>         }
>     }
> },
> "peers": {
>     "peer0.org1.example.com": {
>         "url": "grpcs://20.20.20.23:8051",
>         "eventUrl": "grpcs://20.20.20.23:8053",
>         "grpcOptions": {
>             "ssl-target-name-override": "peer0.org1.example.com"
>         },
>         "tlsCACerts": {
>             "pem": "INSERT_ORG1_CA_CERT"
>         }
>     },
>     "peer0.org2.example.com": {
>         "url": "grpcs://localhost:9051",
>         "eventUrl": "grpcs://localhost:9053",
>         "grpcOptions": {
>             "ssl-target-name-override": "peer0.org2.example.com"
>         },
>         "tlsCACerts": {
>             "pem": "INSERT_ORG2_CA_CERT"
>         }
>     }
> },
> "certificateAuthorities": {
>     "ca.org1.example.com": {
>         "url": "https://20.20.20.23:7054",
>         "caName": "ca.example.com",
>         "httpOptions": {
>             "verify": false
>         }
>     },
>     "ca.org2.example.com": {
>         "url": "https://localhost:8054",
>         "caName": "ca1.example.com",
>         "httpOptions": {
>             "verify": false
>         }
>     }
> } }
> ```

The issue may also be in 
I think my issue may actually be in the network start command. I do (on the peer for admin alice-org1) `composer network start -c PeerAdmin@byfn-network-org1 -n bl-security-network -V 0.0.1 -o endorsementPolicyFile=endorsement-policy.json -A alice-org1 -C alice-org1/admin-pub.pem -A bob-org2 -C bob-org2/admin-pub.pem` after copying the files for bob-org2 from the 2nd peer. I see that network start also creates composer cards, but both of these cards inherit the connection profile of PeerAdmin@byfn-network-org1, whereas bob-org2 should have a connection profile defined for Org2. How can I specify the connection profile for each admin to be different as well?

Answer (score 0):

The multiorg tutorial for composer shows this command for creating the card for 'bob' in org2, with the specific connection profile json for org2.

`composer card create -p /tmp/composer/org2/byfn-network-org2.json -u bob -n trade-network -c bob/admin-pub.pem -k bob/admin-priv.pem`

The connection profile looks OK - I guess you did insert the Certificates.

Comment: Yes, I have a script that inserts the certs and they do appear to be the correct certificates...

Answer (score 0):

I now notice that while `composer network ping` works with the organization 1 card, it says that the version of runtime is 0.19.4 even though I updated to 0.19.5.

> The connection to the network was successfully tested:
>   bl-security-network
>           Business network version: 0.0.1
>           **Composer runtime version: 0.19.4**
>           participant: org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin#alice-org1
>           identity: org.hyperledger.composer.system.Identity#32d8b7d28410fd200ab329b46fd9cb54e0aadf30d8a7bfc8ec5ddfdd154a37b8
>
> Command succeeded

If I run the same commands for a different hyperledger fabric and hyperledger composer network I defined, then I see that the composer runtime version if 0.19.5. How could his be happening? I tried reinstalling composer-cli and the other composer components to no avail....

**UPDATE**: Switched to a different machine where I managed to 0.19.5. Now I see that it is 0.19.5 that is installed, but I still get the ACTIVATION_REQUIRED error...

Comment: You should never see an ACTIVATION_REQUIRED error so curious as to how you got that. Could you paste the following sequence of commands and their exact output. 1. composer -v, 2 composer network ping -c (your card)

Comment: 1. `composer -v` gives `v0.19.5` and 2. `composer network ping -c bob-org2@bl-security-network` gives
`Error: Error trying invoke business network. Error: Error: REQUEST_TIMEOUT
Command failed`    Note that the ACTIVATION_REQUIRED error shows  up only in the peer logs.

Comment: So here https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/3858#issuecomment-389563545 a user reports that the activation required is more of a warning. Could this actually be related to a timeout (as the error suggests)? I would guess this isn't the CHAINCODE_STARTUP_TIMEOUT that is set when creating the container. Perhaps it is one of the timeouts in the network profile? Which would it be?

Comment: **UPDATE:*** Increasing the timeout only made it take longer to reach the REQUEST_TIMEOUT error, so it would seem the issue is the activation_required error that is seen in the peer logs

Comment: @david_k I should also note that trying to start the network from Org2 also leads to a request timeout on startup. I have already tried increasing CHAINCODE_STARTUP_TIMEOUT in the peer settings as is recommended. Could this be a communication issue with the orderer or something along those lines?

Comment: The activation required message in the peer is nothing to worry about and is expected. It also indicates that comms to that peer is working correctly. What it then will happen is an internal TP function is invoked on all the peers to endorse activating that identity and those endorsements will be sent to the orderer. A request timeout shouldn't occur if any peer cannot be contacted but you could get a request timeout if there is a problem sending those endorsements to the orderer. If you get an application log for the network ping that would give more info about what the ping is doing.